# I have python 3.7 in my system and redo command ctrl +Y is not working in python IDLE

Tags: python, windows-10

I am using python 3.7 on my windows 10. I am not able to use the command ctrl + Y in python IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Python IDLE doesn't have `Ctrl + Y` as a shortcut. Instead, use `Ctrl + Shift + Z`. Here's a [list of all shortcuts available in Python IDLE](https://defkey.com/python-idle-for-windows-shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to use "Redo". In IDLE that is Ctrl+Shift+Z.